# Why are startWith and map in angular causing a timeout after deployment but working locally?

Tags: angular, rxjs, serverless

I'm using Serverless to deploy my angular app to aws. Since adding this code
to filter an array for autocomplete

```
this.filteredOptions = this.spotSearch.valueChanges
  .pipe(startWith(''), map(value => this.filter(value))
  );
```

with the filter function being

```
private filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.spotNames.filter(option => 
        option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
}
```

and filteredOptions being

```
public filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;
```

when I deploy I get a message saying internal server error and the logs say that the task timed out after 10 seconds. The code does however work locally. Has anyone come across this before?

**EDIT: In case anyone else if having problems with this, it was because I had to allocate more memory to my Lambda functions in the Management Console.**